# Can't get callback when trying to set mongoose.method

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I want to assign a field from a related model to a schema using `mongoose.methods` in order to use it straghtforward as a property in express middleware. Method as follows:

```
  userSchema.methods.accountGroupOfUser = function accountGroupOfUser(callback) {
    return this.model('User')
      .findById(this.id)
      .populate( {path: 'roles.account', model: 'Account', select: 'groups'} )
      .exec(function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(err, null);
        }
        return callback(null, user.roles.account.groups[0]);
      });
  };
```

and the middleware

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.user = {};
  res.locals.user.accountGroupOfUser = req.user && req.user.accountGroupOfUser();

  next();
});
```

and it returns me `callback is not a function` error.

I looked for various exaples with error similar to this, but it seems like it should work, I am also using functions like this in my app when when i need to make acynchronious calls to database and it works, so I really don't understand why it returns an error.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, your 'accountGroupOfUser' function expects a callback function to be passed to it but you are not passing one.

Try this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.locals.user = {};
    res.locals.user.accountGroupOfUser = req.user && req.user.accountGroupOfUser(function(err, group) {
        // Code here
    });

    next();
});
```

Comment: Can you elabolarate please ? How do I pass tha cllaback right?

Comment: You pass the function that you want to run when your schema method calls 'callback()'. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Now it returns me TypeError: this.model is not a function, but it solved a problem of a callback, thanks.

Comment: You will probably need to do User.findById() and ensure your User model in imported.